# String Replace Only 1 Match Group

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe column that has rows of actor names, like this:

```
r = "c(\"Christian Slater\", \"Tara Reid\", \"Stephen Dorff\", \"Frank C. Turner\")"
```

I want to replace each space with an alternate character like "."  Naively, I thought I could do this:

```
str_replace_all(r, "\\s", ".")
```

But this also inserts the character in between actor names.

[1] "c(\"Christian.Slater\",.\"Tara.Reid\",.\"Stephen.Dorff\",.\"Frank.C..Turner\")"

I tried using match groups, but I am scratching my head at why this doesn't work:

```
str_replace_all(r, "[:alpha:](\\s)[:alpha:]", "\\1.")
```

[1] "c(\"Christia .later\", \"Tar .eid\", \"Stephe .orff\", \"Fran .. Turner\")"

Can anyone explain why I am not matching to the right character? Another minor problem is that I need to correctly match to the "." character for names with a middle initial, but I think that will be easy after I get the basic case working.

Comment: Do you need `str_replace_all(r, ",\\s", ",.")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use a regex lookaround to replace the space after any character that is not a comma (`,`)

```
str_replace_all(r, "(?<!,)\\s+", ".")
#[1] "c(\"Christian.Slater\", \"Tara.Reid\", \"Stephen.Dorff\", \"Frank.C..Turner\")"
```

Or replace the space after a lower case character with `.`

```
str_replace_all(r, "(?<=[a-z])\\s", ".")
#[1] "c(\"Christian.Slater\", \"Tara.Reid\", \"Stephen.Dorff\", \"Frank.C. Turner\")"
```

Or it could be

```
str_replace_all(r, "(?<=[A-Za-z])\\.*\\s", ".")
#[1] "c(\"Christian.Slater\", \"Tara.Reid\", \"Stephen.Dorff\", \"Frank.C.Turner\")"
```

NOTE: It is not clear about the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I believe that just want one . when there is already a .   so

```
str_replace_all(r, "([:alpha:])\\.?\\s", "\\1.")
[1] "c(\"Christian.Slater\", \"Tara.Reid\", \"Stephen.Dorff\", \"Frank.C.Turner\")"
```